# How do you check to see what your drupal site looks like as different types of users?

Tags: users

I hope to find a way to stay logged in as admin but see what it looks like to an unauthenticated user and other types of users too, if possible.

I ask firstly because right now I am trying to make certain changes to the css file which means I need to check what the change looks like to an unauthenticated user. Sometimes it is easy to see more or less what I want in the admin pages but I do find I can get tripped up by this sometimes and also find I need to clean the cache of my browser before I can actually see how it looks. This is something that I do not really want to be taking much time over as I want to be able to correct it quickly if I made something look terrible.

Aside from that I do also have a few different kinds of users with various permission rights and when I change something I want to check that a change is doing what I want and all the users are still seeing the right things. Again, it is not an ideal situation for me to have to log out and in as each type of user for this type of thing as it can expose parts of the site if a mistake has been made or there is some bug rearing its head etc.

Aside from the aforementioned issues I have with needing to log in and out after every little change I make to the site, it makes the whole process pretty laborious. It suddenly dawned on me that someone else might have thought this too and that there is some way to work around it without compromising anything. Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

For the anonymous user you will require a second browser (not logged in) or you will have to log out to view the changes. For other roles, check out the [Masquerade](http://drupal.org/project/masquerade) module. It permits you to rapidly switch user roles by masquerading as a user with that role.

Comment: Thanks, I just installed and actually I think writing "Anonymous" inMenu Quick Switch user  will allow to include non members to the list but I have not figured out how I use the switcher once I named the members to switch between yet! If you want I will edit your answer and add a screen shot to show how to include it.

Comment: Add away! Happy to help.